# What does this command in Perl do?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

An entire shell command can be executed like a function, returning its 
output in place. This is done by surrounding the command with parentheses 
and prefixing a dollar sign:

```
u$(perl -e 'print "na";')me
```

Why do we type `u` + the command then followed by `me`? Why don't we just do this?

```
$(perl -e 'print "uname";')
```

What is the differences and the goal of the first method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author's just being cute. There's no practical reason to write:

```
u$(perl -e 'print "na";')me
```

versus:

```
$(perl -e 'print "uname";')
```

They do the same thing. Really, there's no need for Perl at all when it comes down to it. In a real script you'd just write:

```
uname
```

Answer (score 2):

The author want to hide the word 'uname' from a grep search. Your intentions are not good...